# How do I find the filepath I need to run a cronjob?

Tags: amazon-ec2, cron

I have a file, run.py currently on a working ec2 instance. I want to run it every hour.

Here is the cronjob I wrote:

```
0 * * * * python run.py
```

However, this doesn't work because it needs the full filepath to run.py. However for the life of me I cannot figure out how to find that filepath. All the tutorials I have read just magically have that filepath at the ready somehow.

Comment: How do you know you have the file if you don't know where it is?

Comment: When I ssh into ec2, I arrive in a directory. The file is in a folder in that directory. However, that first folder isn't the home directory.

Comment: So https://duckduckgo.com/?q=what+directory+am+i+in+linux&t=h_&ia=qa ?

Comment: just do: `0 * * * * /usr/bin/env python `/the/directory/where/the/co/is`run.py`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming a Linux installation, you could use "find" to find the path:

```
find / -name "run.py" -print
```

This will search the whole disc and might take a few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

`realpath run.py` will do it, if you're in the directory that `run.py` resides in. `locate run.py` will find it (after a `sudo updatedb` unless that's already run), but might return lots of other stuff that contain the string `run.py`.